# Galaxy Superclusters

Tags: cosmology, gravity, astrophysics, galaxies, structure-formation

Okay quick question... why is it that when galaxies group together in superclusters they form a sort of branch-like shape? I personally would think they’d all just group together in some sphere or disk just like regular galaxies.. So what’s the physics behind the branching?

Answer (score 1):

galaxy clusters are formed where there was higher density of dark matter after the inflation epoch. The dark matter creates some gravitational wells in where the galaxy clusters are formed. These dark matter clusters are connected by lower density dark mater regions which may look like a branch. Some galaxies may have been formed on these branches.